# Deploy a Page based on a Custom Layout in SP2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm able to successfully deploy a custom page layout and see it in the masterpage gallery. I can also manually create pages from this layout.

What I want to do is have a page in my site definition based on the custom layout deploy automatically with the package.

How do I deploy a page and tell that page which layout to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using module you can create Page instance from your `PageLayout`

I guess your PageLayouts PageName is `Home.aspx` than instance name should be `Home.aspx`

hope your Pagelayouts upload on `_catalogs/masterpage` directory.

```
 <Module Name="PagesLayouts"
      Url="_catalogs/masterpage"
      Path=""
      RootWebOnly="False">
  <File Url="YourModuleName/Home.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE"></File>
</Module>
```

than:

```
<Module Name="CustomPages" Url="Pages" Path="" RootWebOnly="FALSE">
 <File Name="Home.aspx" Url="Home.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Path="Home.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
  <Property Name="Title" Value="Home" />
  <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Home.aspx" />
  <Property Name="ContentType" Value="Page" />
 </File>
</Module>
```

see here : http://kamilmka.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/create-sharepoint-page-instance-from-a-feature/

### Update :

i have just create demo project for understand properly. you can see my solution structure.
just added one module name is PageLayouts and put one PageLayout Page.

[image]

full Element.xml file of Module i have used :

```
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <Module Name="PageLayouts" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" Path="" RootWebOnly="TRUE">
 <File Path="PageLayouts\CustomPageLayouts.aspx" Url="CustomPageLayouts.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
    <Property Name="Title" Value="Custom General Page" />
    <Property Name="MasterPageDescription" Value="Custom General page layout" />
    <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;" />
    <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/WelcomeSplash.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/WelcomeSplash.png" />
  <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_welcomepage_name;;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D4;#" />
  </File>
 </Module>
 <!--Create Page instance from Page layouts of CustomPageLayouts.aspx-->
 <Module Name="CustomPages" Url="Pages" Path="" RootWebOnly="FALSE">
   <File Name="Home.aspx" Url="Home.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Path="PageLayouts\CustomPageLayouts.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
    <Property Name="Title" Value="Home" />
    <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/CustomPageLayouts.aspx"/>
    <Property Name="ContentType" Value="Page" />
  </File>
</Module>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Do I need to actually include a home.aspx in the module? Or am I telling SP to create one?

Comment: yes.u need to first deployed your pagelayout on masterpage catalogs.than after give reference on below module.

Comment: I have created the module, and added the property nodes to the element file node, but the page which is created is not based on my template. What can I show you to help?